# Scroll to anchor on specific page (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, url, scroll, anchor

I'm building a Wordpress website and I'm trying to scroll to an anchor on specific pages. My idea is to detect on which page the visitor is based on de URL. If the URL is `http://website.com/targetterm/category/test` I would like the script to detect the term `targetterm` and automatically scroll to an anchor on these pages.

Is there anyone who has an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `targetterm` in your WordPress installation ? Is that a custom post type or is that a variable you added to the url ?

Comment: `targetterm` is a slug created by a plugin (Web 2.0 Directory). So I think a custom post type?